# Using AntiXss to encode html Attribute in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass an id from my controller to my view and encode this value in the Antixss function but I am getting an error.

This is my code

```
input  type="hidden" name="Moderator" value="@AntiXss.HtmlAttributeEncode(ViewBag.ModeratorID)" readOnly="readonly" />
```

The error message is

```
The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.HtmlAttributeEncode(string)' has some invalid arguments
```

Comment: Is ModeratorID a string?  Have you tried to append .ToString()?  Such as `ViewBag.ModeratorID.ToString()`

Comment: Thanks alot, I am grateful for you comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewBag` is a dynamic type, so call `ToString()` on ModeratorID.

```
@AntiXss.HtmlAttributeEncode(ViewBag.ModeratorID.ToString())
```